# How the cufon will support Arabic language?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cufon

I have a free cufon template and I want to change it to Arabic.
it's consist of two files that related to language:

```
LiberationSans.font.js
cufon-yui.js
```

I changed "LiberationSans.font.js" with "Tahoma.font.js" , but It still does not work.

Thanks for your advice ...

Comment: have you found a solution to this?

Comment: I think you need to create your font files with the correct character sets in the first place but unfortunately, I haven't been able to achieve this. I always ended up defaulting to standard text for arabic/hebrew sites.

Answer (score 3):

You can use bifon font generator , it's like cufon but made for `rtl` persian language
Download it with examples at [DOWNLOAD LINK](http://www.averta.net/downloads/downloader.php?product=bifon&name=bifon_package.zip&hash=2726a91c782fbf4038298adb06c19914)

this software designed for persian language and can work arabic too .

Comment: This download link has expired.

Answer (score 0):

embed the fonts with css
eg.

```
@font-face {
  font-family:a-remote-font-name;
  src: source url;
  [font-weight:XXpx];
  [font-style:regular html style];
}
```

add to HTML head `<link href="./font-face.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

and the CSS should be something that

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Gideas Font-face Demo";
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local("âک؛"), url("fonts/thickTitleFont.ttf") format("truetype");
}

#font-face-arabic-text-title
{
margin:auto;
width:400px;
font: 150% 'Gideas Font-face Demo','Simplified Arabic';
color:blue;
font-size:40px;
direction:rtl;
}
```